# jq: concatenate two values from data set

Tags: json, concatenation, jq

I've been messing with this for about an hour now and I'm pretty new to `jq` and `json` in general.  I come from a systems background and have pretty good `bash` scripting skills, but this `jq` stuff is really giving me a hard time.

Sample `json` output:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Cluster B"
}
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Cluster A"
}
```

Desired output:

```
"1:Cluster A"
"2:Cluster B"
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You could do the sorting after invoking jq, but one way to do the sorting without any postprocessing is to use the -s command-line option with the following filter:

```
sort_by(.id)[]
| "\(.id): \(.name)"
```

Using string interpolation here avoids having to convert .id to a string explicitly.

### Variants

If the input file were much larger than the expected output, it might be advisable to avoid the -s option in favor of `inputs` and the -n command-line option.  For example:

```
[inputs | (.id|tostring) + ":" + (.name|tostring)] | sort[]
```

Comment: How does that look like with the `jq` command that starts as `jq '.results[] | {id,name}` (the output of this is what is described above).  How would I write out the rest of the `jq` command.

Comment: Just continue the pipeline: `jq '.results[] | {id,name} | sort_by(.id)[] | "\(.id): \(.name)"'`.  But putting long pipelines in a file (whether a shell script or a .jq file) is the way to go.

Comment: the variant would be an ascii sort rather than numeric? interesting that you can increase the efficiency on the read side by chopping up the input.